# Electromagnetism Physic

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

Hiii guys please help me.

The question is that Mary and her friends are camping in Kuala Woh. While they are hiking in the jungle, they lost their way. They have a compass but the marking on it has worn off. They also have a flashlight with a battery and a length of wire. How are they able to identify the north pole on the compass needle?

Pleaseee help meee:(

Comment: What do you know about nature?

Comment: Asking questions in physics.stack like their lives depended on it.

Comment: My guess is that this is a question about which way the current in a length of wire will make the needle go (given they can identify the plus and minus on the battery). Or maybe they should use the wire to catch rabbits and wait for their friends to notice they haven't posted on Facebook for over an hour.

Comment: Maybe read this: https://www.khanacademy.org/test-prep/mcat/physical-processes/magnetism-mcat/a/using-the-right-hand-rule

Answer (score 1):

If they have a compass i guess you're either guessing between which is north and which is south? The sun rises in the east and sets in the west so this can easily be decided.

Answer (score 0):

By coiling the wire around a pencil or similar object, then running a current through it, they could create a magnetic field and see how it interacted with their compass needle. It is very unwise to go hiking in the jungle, especially by yourself, but I see Mary has friends. At best, her journey will be arduous and uncomfortable, with oppressive humidity, numerous biting insects. and in some places lots of land leeches. Snakes are less of a danger than many people suppose. As the previous answer said, the rising or setting sun would give some idea of direction, but often in rainforest the sky is cloudy. Assuming that Mary successfully identifies the north pole of her compass needle and they march on a compass bearing, it is usually impractical to march long distances on a compass bearing unless the terrain is very flat. In Malaysia, the jungle is often mountainous, so you have to follow the contours of the land, even if you happen to be a very fit and strong soldier. Map reading is extremely difficult when yu cant see more than 20 or 30 yards in front of you. and needs a lot of experience, a compass and a good map. If all else fails and you are lost (very easy to do in jungle, which is why even locals hesitate to go far in), the best plan is to find a stream and follow it down. Sooner or later, when you are thoroughly exhausted, you will probably find some sign of human habitation.

Answer (score 0):

You connect the flashlight to the wire and hang it from a tree branch as a pendulum. Over some time the plane of the pendulum will precess due to earth's rotation ([Foucault's pendulum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foucault_pendulum)), telling you which direction the Earth turns even in the night and hence telling you which way is north on the compass... oh, Kuala Woh is nearly at the equator (4 degree north), so the precession rate is just one degree per hour. Back to the drawing board, where Michael has apparently left a handy coil wrapped around my pen that could create a known magnetic field...